# Make the server ignoring the underscore in file names when requested by URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Do you think that there is a trick in htaccess to to make the browser download the file `my_file_21.pdf` if the user access this one with the path  `http://example.com/files/myfile21.pdf`?

And bonus point if the both paths below :

- `http://example.com/files/myfile21.pdf`
- `http://example.com/files/my_file_21.pdf`

works for the file on the server : `my_file_21.pdf`

Comment: There probably isn’t a trivial way to do this - when you request `myfile21.pdf`, the server would basically have to _guess_ where to insert the underscores - how is it supposed to know that the existing file would be `my_file_21.pdf`, and not for example `myfile_21.pdf` or `myf_ile_21.pdf` …? (Not sure if `MultiViews` could handle that case, perhaps.)

Comment: It might work the other way around - if you make sure all your files are actually stored on the server as `myfile21.pdf` - then you could try and _remove_ any underscores from whatever was requested, so that you internally rewrite this to the version without any underscores at all, so that the server can then actually find the matching file.

Comment: Well actually it is not really what I need.
Here is my problem : 
I have more than 27 000 files on the server and nearly more of them contains underscore. And in my database I have +/- 27 000 links that point to the files without referring to the underscore.

The files where moved from a previous server and I suppose the previous one had a rule that make the match between my_file_21.pdf and http://myhost.com/files/myfile21.pdf

I can't change the link to match the filename cause I can't guess where to put the underscores. And I don't really want to rename all the files

Comment: _“cause I can't guess where to put the underscores”_ - well if you can’t, then how should your server …? The only way I could see this working without massive effort, would be `MultiViews` - with that, the server actually reads what files physically exist, and then tries to find a match among those. With just URL rewriting, I would not see any other way then “creating” all possible variations somehow and then checking if that exists as a physical file (`m_yfile21.pdf` - no? `my_file21.pdf` - no? `myf_ile21.pdf` - no?) - but that would get _really_ nasty.

Comment: I thought we could approach the subject the other way around.

Rather than trying to add underscores in the name sent in the URL before comparing with the contents of the folder, couldn't we ignore the underscores of the files on the server before making the comparison?

Comment: No, with a RewriteCond and the f/d flags, you can not do it in that direction. Have you tried yet if it works with MultiViews enabled maybe?

Comment: Ok I tried with the MultiViews but it did'nt work.

I built a new solution that redirect the requested uri to a php function that made the research in file list and then send the file as result. It is not as clean as I wanted to do with an htaccess but it works.

Comment: Could you not remove all the underscores in the files on your server? It is then relatively trivial to _remove_ underscores in any requests if you need to. "php function that made the research in file" - do you mean "search"? If you go with this approach I would certainly pre-generate a 1-1 mapping of the _differences_ - so no filesystem "searching" is required.